# How to resolve needs dependency when testing ember app

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, mocha.js

I am trying to test a controller and for simplicity lets name it 'A'. In the template for my "A" controller, I render another controller "B" like:

```
<div> blah blah </div>
{{render 'B'}}
```

my "B" Controller in turn needs "C". Given this long chain, I was trying to write a unit test for "A" controller and running into dependency error like:

**Error: Assertion Failed: < AS.B:ember571 > needs controller:c but it does not exist**

I feel like I need to do something in my beforeEach method. Currently it looks something like :

```
beforeEach(function () {
        container = AS.__container__;
        store = container.lookup('store:main');

        Ember.run(function () {
            store.find('A').then(function (data) {

                //WHAT CAN I DO HERE TO SET CORRECT DEPENDENCY!!
                //container.register('controller:c', {});
                //container.register('controller:b', AS.BController.create({container: container}));

                controller = AS.__container__.lookup('controller:a');
                controller.set('content', data);


                view = AS.AView.create({
                    container: container,
                    controller: controller,
                    context: controller
                });

                view.append();
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks,
Dee

Comment: You're going to find it's significantly easier to use the built in testing and qunit.  Then you can just visit a route, and grab the controllers/views from the container and inspect them then.

Comment: doesnt this helps you http://codingvalue.com/blog/testing-emberjs-controllers/

Comment: You need to create a container and register the dependency `controllers`

Comment: suggest to have a look at EAK on how they resolve the dependcies.. https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/tests/helpers/isolated_container.js#L3-l16

Comment: Hi @selva-G I was actually following the link you have posted but couldn't get things to work. Thanks for the last link, I'll try to add the helper and see if it solves my issue. Thanks.